# SublimeREPL on Sublime Text 3 not importing Python 2.7 modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I have been trying to configure SublimeText 3 to run SublimeREPL, setting everything so it runs as IDLE, or PyCharm IDE, but, after trying different options I checked in SO, it keeps returning:

```
>>> import pandas 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas

>>> import os
>>> os.environ['PYTHONPATH']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'
```

I have tried editing the SublimeREPL.sublime-settings file with the default extend path file you can see at the FAQ site of SublimeREPL, but still does not work.

Does anyone know how this could be solved?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the problem for you, but I was getting the exact same error and learned that by opening sublime text from the command line (e.g. 'subl .' to open the directory, once you have that shortcut set up) you get one PATH- and if you open sublime text from Spotlight Search you get another PATH.  Try opening sublime text from the command line once you've confirmed you can import pandas in an interactive command line session and hopefully it will work.